# Do I need merge training and validation set together to train for testing set?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am working on a challenge that aims to segment object. It has 6 subjects in training set and 18 subjects in the testing set. In training data, I separated it into 4 subjects for training and 2 subjects for validation. After verifying my network is working fine by looking at validation loss. Now, I will apply my network for testing. Do I need merge training set and validation set together (same as 6 subjects as the beginning) to make a new model to apply it to the testing set since I have a limited training data? Or I just use the model that trained from 4 subjects? If I merge, I do not know when I must be stopped (overfitting often occur in the limited training set) (Using validation set, I will know it). Thanks all

Comment: You want to train on *WAY* more than 6 subjects.

Comment: No. Just 4 subjects or 6 subjects?

Comment: My question is that I have two options: training on 4 subjects and I can see the loss of validation (2 subjects), or the second option is training on 6 subjects without validation

Comment: If you're not tuning hyperparameters, you don't need a validation set.

Comment: I need tuning and early stopping to deal with limited training dataset.

Comment: Well, you've identified the pros and cons of each strategy. Decide which aspects are most important, and pick the method that aligns with them.

Comment: Do you think which option is better? One is training is larger dataset (6 subjects) but does not know which point needs to stop (overfitting), one is training in smaller dataset but know the stop point

Comment: Like I said, you need to train on *WAY* more data. The [scikit-learn machine learning map](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/) provides a target of at least 50.